# How to convert it into time seconds, mins,hours,days,months years

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Team,

I got response date from server.

```
"createTime": "2016-10-07T19:22:34.3192343+00:00"
```

based on date changes i want to check this it on device (mins,hours,days,months years) completed.

Is a way, how to calculate completed time?
based on services request `"createTime" : "2016-10-07T19:22:34.3192343+00:00"`

**Result value should be 30 min.  After one hour 1:30 min after 2 days it will be 2 days**

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString* format = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";

    // Set up an NSDateFormatter for UTC time zone
    NSDateFormatter* formatterUtc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatterUtc setDateFormat:format];
    [formatterUtc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    // Cast the input string to NSDate
    NSDate* utcDate = [formatterUtc dateFromString:[formatterUtc stringFromDate:@""2016-10-07T19:22:34.3192343+00:00" "]];

    // Set up an NSDateFormatter for the device's local time zone
    NSDateFormatter* formatterLocal = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatterLocal setDateFormat:format];
    [formatterLocal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    // Create local NSDate with time zone difference
    NSDate* localDate = [formatterUtc dateFromString:[formatterLocal stringFromDate:utcDate]];


    NSTimeInterval seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:localDate];
```

Comment: Not the exact answer.